Training a huggingface model on streaming data
Problem:
Something is not correct with set up and args.  The training hangs and does not complete the eval step.
Background and Code:
I'm finetuning a whisper model on Catalan Common Voice data using the huggingface tutorial here.   The Corpus 17.0 version of dataset is 72 GB, so only difference in this code with tutorial is that the datasets are streaming=True upon load_dataset.  Loading this dataset without streaming maxes out the RAM on Colab, even with Pro subscription.  With streaming, can load the data.
!pip install -q datasets evaluate jiwer

from datasets import Dataset, load_dataset, DatasetDict, concatenate_datasets

common_voice = DatasetDict()

common_voice['train']= load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_17_0", "ca", split="train", streaming=True)#.select_columns(["audio", "sentence"])#,streaming=True)
common_voice['val'] = load_dataset("mozilla-foundation/common_voice_17_0", "ca", split="validation",streaming=True)#.select_columns(["audio", "sentence"])#,streaming=True)

print(common_voice)

common_voice['train'] = common_voice['train'].select_columns(["audio", "sentence"])
common_voice['val'] = common_voice['val'].select_columns(["audio", "sentence"])

from transformers.models.whisper.tokenization_whisper import TO_LANGUAGE_CODE

TO_LANGUAGE_CODE

from transformers import WhisperProcessor

processor = WhisperProcessor.from_pretrained(
    "openai/whisper-small", language="spanish", task="transcribe"
)

common_voice["train"].features

from datasets import Audio

sampling_rate = processor.feature_extractor.sampling_rate
common_voice['train'] = common_voice['train'].cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=sampling_rate))
common_voice['val'] = common_voice['val'].cast_column("audio", Audio(sampling_rate=sampling_rate))

def prepare_dataset(example):
    audio = example["audio"]

    example = processor(
        audio=audio["array"],
        sampling_rate=audio["sampling_rate"],
        text=example["sentence"],
    )

    # compute input length of audio sample in seconds
    example["input_length"] = len(audio["array"]) / audio["sampling_rate"]

    return example

common_voice['train'] = common_voice['train'].map(
    prepare_dataset)#, remove_columns=common_voice.column_names["train"], num_proc=1
# )
common_voice['val'] = common_voice['val'].map(
    prepare_dataset)

max_input_length = 30.0 #cut off for whisper

def is_audio_in_length_range(length):
    return length < max_input_length

common_voice["train"] = common_voice["train"].filter(
    is_audio_in_length_range,
    input_columns=["input_length"],
)

# new size of train.  Could measure number of hours train here.
common_voice["train"].features

import torch

from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Union


@dataclass
class DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding:
    processor: Any

    def __call__(
        self, features: List[Dict[str, Union[List[int], torch.Tensor]]]
    ) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
        # split inputs and labels since they have to be of different lengths and need different padding methods
        # first treat the audio inputs by simply returning torch tensors
        input_features = [
            {"input_features": feature["input_features"][0]} for feature in features
        ]
        batch = self.processor.feature_extractor.pad(input_features, return_tensors="pt")

        # get the tokenized label sequences
        label_features = [{"input_ids": feature["labels"]} for feature in features]
        # pad the labels to max length
        labels_batch = self.processor.tokenizer.pad(label_features, return_tensors="pt")

        # replace padding with -100 to ignore loss correctly
        labels = labels_batch["input_ids"].masked_fill(
            labels_batch.attention_mask.ne(1), -100
        )

        # if bos token is appended in previous tokenization step,
        # cut bos token here as it's append later anyways
        if (labels[:, 0] == self.processor.tokenizer.bos_token_id).all().cpu().item():
            labels = labels[:, 1:]

        batch["labels"] = labels

        return batch

data_collator = DataCollatorSpeechSeq2SeqWithPadding(processor=processor)

import evaluate
metric = evaluate.load("wer")

from transformers.models.whisper.english_normalizer import BasicTextNormalizer

normalizer = BasicTextNormalizer()


def compute_metrics(pred):
    pred_ids = pred.predictions
    label_ids = pred.label_ids

    # replace -100 with the pad_token_id
    label_ids[label_ids == -100] = processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id

    # we do not want to group tokens when computing the metrics
    pred_str = processor.batch_decode(pred_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
    label_str = processor.batch_decode(label_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)

    # compute orthographic wer
    wer_ortho = 100 * metric.compute(predictions=pred_str, references=label_str)

    # compute normalised WER
    pred_str_norm = [normalizer(pred) for pred in pred_str]
    label_str_norm = [normalizer(label) for label in label_str]
    # filtering step to only evaluate the samples that correspond to non-zero references:
    pred_str_norm = [
        pred_str_norm[i] for i in range(len(pred_str_norm)) if len(label_str_norm[i]) > 0
    ]
    label_str_norm = [
        label_str_norm[i]
        for i in range(len(label_str_norm))
        if len(label_str_norm[i]) > 0
    ]

    wer = 100 * metric.compute(predictions=pred_str_norm, references=label_str_norm)

    return {"wer_ortho": wer_ortho, "wer": wer}

model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("openai/whisper-small")

from functools import partial

# disable cache during training since it's incompatible with gradient checkpointing
model.config.use_cache = False

# set language and task for generation and re-enable cache
model.generate = partial(
    model.generate, language="spanish", task="transcribe", use_cache=True
)

from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainingArguments

training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./whisper-small-ca",  # name on the HF Hub
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=1,  # increase by 2x for every 2x decrease in batch size
    learning_rate=1e-5,
    lr_scheduler_type="constant_with_warmup",
    warmup_steps=50,
    max_steps=500,  # increase to 4000 if you have your own GPU or a Colab paid plan
    gradient_checkpointing=True,
    fp16=True,
    fp16_full_eval=True,
    evaluation_strategy="steps",
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    predict_with_generate=True,
    generation_max_length=225,
    save_steps=100,
    eval_steps=100,
    logging_steps=25,
    report_to=["tensorboard"],
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="wer",
    greater_is_better=False,
    push_to_hub=True,
)

from transformers import Seq2SeqTrainer

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    args=training_args,
    model=model,
    train_dataset=common_voice["train"],
    eval_dataset=common_voice["val"],
    data_collator=data_collator,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
    tokenizer=processor,
)

trainer.train()

Reading metadata...: 1146209it [00:28, 40426.93it/s]
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/checkpoint.py:464: UserWarning: torch.utils.checkpoint: the use_reentrant parameter should be passed explicitly. In version 2.4 we will raise an exception if use_reentrant is not passed. use_reentrant=False is recommended, but if you need to preserve the current default behavior, you can pass use_reentrant=True. Refer to docs for more details on the differences between the two variants.
  warnings.warn(
 [500/500 04:28, Epoch 1/9223372036854775807]
Step    Training Loss   Validation Loss
Reading metadata...: 16402it [00:00, 19432.46it/s]

I was expecting to see results: Step, Training Loss,  Validation Loss with WER and WER Ortho
Something like this from the
Training Loss   Epoch   Step   Validation Loss  WerOrtho   Wer
0.136   1.63    500   0.1727   63.8972   14.0661
